# Does our support chat need to be HIPAA compliant?

Tags: compliance, hipaa

We are currently using olark to provide an instant chat support feature to our customers. Customer typically ask about outages, setup issues, etc. We are in the process of trying to become HIPAA compliant but I just found out olark is not HIPAA compliant. I am unsure if we even need them to be in our scenario.

Our product generates sound files that could contain ePHI. That would mean a customer would have to actively make the decision themselves to download a sound file from our product and upload the ePHI sound file to the olark chat window. We would never ask them to transmit this information because we would never need it. Would we be non-compliant if we continued to use olark for customer support?

Comment: I think this is a question for your HIPAA assessor.